# Display tables in R markdown using loop

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to display multiple data frames in R markdown using a for loop.
I have the data frames named in a pattern e.g. CP_DD_comb1, BK_DD_comb1 and so on.
I tried this thing:

```
for (i in c("CP","BK","IT","WP")){
  for(j in c("DD","SI")){
    data <- get(paste0(i,"_",j,"_comb1"))
    print(data)
  }
}
```

But this didn't work

How can I display these tables ?

Thanks for help

Comment: That should have worked.  Please show us the result of `ls()`; maybe the names aren't exactly what you think they are.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the chunk option `code`](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-chunk) to construct the code for the chunk:

````
```{r, code = apply(expand.grid(c("CP","BK","IT","WP"), c("DD","SI")), 1, function(x) sprintf("%s_%s_comb1", x[1], x[2]))}
```
````

The code is a little long but shouldn't be too hard to understand if you break it down:

```
dfs = expand.grid(c("CP","BK","IT","WP"), c("DD","SI"))
dfs
```

```
  Var1 Var2
1   CP   DD
2   BK   DD
3   IT   DD
4   WP   DD
5   CP   SI
6   BK   SI
7   IT   SI
8   WP   SI
```

```
sprintf("%s_%s_comb1", dfs[, 1], dfs[, 2])
```

```
[1] "CP_DD_comb1" "BK_DD_comb1" "IT_DD_comb1" "WP_DD_comb1" "CP_SI_comb1"
[6] "BK_SI_comb1" "IT_SI_comb1" "WP_SI_comb1"
```

Then the above code chunk is equivalent to:

````
```{r}
CP_DD_comb1
BK_DD_comb1
IT_DD_comb1
WP_DD_comb1
CP_SI_comb1
BK_SI_comb1
IT_SI_comb1
WP_SI_comb1
```
````

You don't need `for`-loops or `get()` or `print()`.

---

If you are sure that the pattern `*_*_comb1` can identify all objects you want, here is a much simpler solution:

````
```{r, code = grep('_comb1$', ls(), value = TRUE)}
```
````

If you want to be stricter:

````
```{r, code = grep('^[A-Z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}_comb1$', ls(), value = TRUE)}
```
````

Comment: How to format this into a table, because using this all columns do not remain in same table.

Comment: If they have identical column attributes, you can `rbind()` them: `code = paste0('rbind(', paste(OBJECT_NAMES_YOU_GOT_ABOVE, collapse = ', '), ')')`.